# openlayers3 load vector data in WFS format, but not displaying it

Tags: maps, openlayers-3

I can see, that WFS data is loading by monitoring cache/network tab in FF/Chrom(ium), but no featured vectors are being displayed on the map.
I've even tried to disable the OSM layer beneath, so, that I can only see the vector layer, but nothing is visible.
When dragging the map area zooming in/out, I see, that new data is being loaded, but nothing appears on the map.
What did I do wrong?
Openlayers Version: v3.19.1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

 <title>The Book of OpenLayers3 - Code samples</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="progr/nm/ol.css" type="text/css">
 <script src="progr/nm/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="progr/nm/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
.map {
 width: calc(100% - 9px);
 height: 500px;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 20px black;
 border: 3px solid blue;
 float: left;
}
.tree {
 width: auto;
 border: 3px solid red;
 background: yellow;
 float: left;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<dev id='mapAjax' class='map col-sm-6'></dev>

<script>
var layerSrc = {
 srvVec: new ol.source.Vector({
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection){
   $.ajax(
    'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typename=osm:water_areas&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox='+extent.join(',')
   ).then(function(response){
    var format = new ol.format.WFS({
     featureNS: 'http://openstreetmap.org',
     featureType: 'water_areas'
    });
    layerSrc['srvVec'].addFeatures(format.readFeatures(
     response,
     {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'}
    ));
   });
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(new ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}))
//  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
 })
};

var layers = {
 OSM: new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()}),
 vec: new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: layerSrc['srvVec'],
  style: new ol.style.Style({
   stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'green',
    width: 2
   })
  })
 })
};

var view = new ol.View({
 center: ol.proj.transform([-75.923853, 45.428736], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
 maxZoom: 19,
 zoom: 11
});

var maps = {
 mapAjax: new ol.Map({
  target: 'mapAjax',
  renderer: 'canvas',
//  layers: [layers['OSM'], layers['vec']],
  layers: [layers['vec']],
  view: view
 })
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

### P.S.:

Updated openlayers to version v3.20.1 - didn't help.
Examples from:
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs-getfeature.html
and:
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html
didn't clarify, either.

Comment: Just remove these two lines from your wfs format `featureNS: 'http://openstreetmap.org',
     featureType: 'water_areas'` so your format declaration should be ---> `var format = new ol.format.WFS({})`

Comment: Thank You! It helped. Then, I've tried to reverse, to see, maybe it's one of these params. So - 'featureType' param caused it, but with 'featureNS' enabled, it works. I would mark your answer, if it wouldn't be in the comment section. Otherwise, I don't know how.

Comment: No need for amenities mate. After all it wasnt a proper answer, it was just a tip. glad to help